# Is Wolfram Cloud going to support GPU training?

Tags: neural-networks, wolfram-cloud, gpu

Is Wolfram Cloud going to support GPU training?

Is there any other possibility for training a neural net (in WL) on a cloud like AWS, Floydhub, or so?

I think this concerns lots of people.

Comment: You can definitely train neural networks in AWS, presuming you buy a license for the server. e.g. if you buy a Mathematica for home users you get two licenses, and you can put one of them on an Amazon EC2 server.

Comment: Okay, do you mean one license can be installed on an Amazon EC2 server? Is this in accordance with the license agreement?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the licenses but I would presume that installing it on an EC2 server is like installing it on any other computer, given that it is for your private use. For more information, see the question [Training Neural Networks on Cloud GPUs (Wolfram Cloud / AWS / Paperspace /etc)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/181115/731)

Comment: I believe it is on the roadmap but I think it's still a long way off.